# Симуляция движения в 2D игре, Android canvas

Tags: java, android, canvas

Пишу простенький раннер, движение объекта (того, кто бежит) симулирую сдвигом на определенное расстояние картинки на бэкграунде (фона).

Но почему-то прорисовка очень медлительна, нет плавности, такое ощущение, что игра выдает 5-10 фпс.

В чем может быть проблема? Вот кусок кода класса, отвечающего за прорисовку :

```
public class GameView extends View {
    public GameView(Context context) {
        MyTimerTask myTimerTask = new MyTimerTask();
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(myTimerTask,0, 17);

    }


    class MyTimerTask extends java.util.TimerTask {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            long ticksPS = 60;
            long startTime;
            long sleepTime;
            while (playing) {

                startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

                try {
                    draw();
                    player.move();
                    STEP_COUNTER += 1;

                    sleepTime = ticksPS - (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);

                    try {

                        if (sleepTime > 0)
                            Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
                        else
                            Thread.sleep(10);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {}
            }
        }

    }


    ...

    private void draw() {
        BitmapConstants bitmapConstants = new BitmapConstants(getContext());

        if (surfaceHolder.getSurface().isValid()) {

            canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();


            if (STEP_COUNTER % 4 == 3)
                currentStep = bitmapConstants.firstStepAnimationBitmap;
            if (STEP_COUNTER % 4 == 2)
                currentStep = bitmapConstants.secondStepAnimationBitmap;
            if (STEP_COUNTER % 4 == 1)
                currentStep = bitmapConstants.thirdStepAnimationBitmap;
            if (STEP_COUNTER % 4 == 0)
                currentStep = bitmapConstants.forthStepAnimationBitmap;

            canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapConstants.background, player.backgroundLayer, 0, paint);

            canvas.drawBitmap(
                    currentStep,
                    player.getX(),
                    player.getY(),
                    paint);
            surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);

        }

    }


}
```

BitmapConstants.java:

```
public class BitmapConstants {
    private CompressedImageBitmap compressedImageBitmap;
    public final  Bitmap firstStepAnimationBitmap;
    public final  Bitmap secondStepAnimationBitmap;
    public final  Bitmap thirdStepAnimationBitmap;
    public final  Bitmap forthStepAnimationBitmap;
    public final  Bitmap background;

    private Context context;
    public BitmapConstants(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        compressedImageBitmap = new CompressedImageBitmap(context);
        background = compressedImageBitmap.getBackground();
        firstStepAnimationBitmap = compressedImageBitmap.getFirstStepAnimationBitmap();
        secondStepAnimationBitmap = compressedImageBitmap.getSecondStepAnimationBitmap();
        thirdStepAnimationBitmap = compressedImageBitmap.getThirdStepAnimationBitmap();
        forthStepAnimationBitmap = compressedImageBitmap.getForthStepAnimationBitmap();

    }
}
```

CompressedImageBitmap.java:

```
public class CompressedImageBitmap {

    private Bitmap firstAnimationBitmap;
    private Bitmap secondAnimationBitmap;
    private Bitmap thirdAnimationBitmap;
    private Bitmap forthAnimationBitmap;

    private Context context;

    private final int COMPRESS_HEIGHT = 360;
    private final int COMPRESS_WIDTH = 360;


    public CompressedImageBitmap(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public Bitmap getBackground() {
        return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                R.drawable.background);
    }

    public Bitmap getFirstStepAnimationBitmap() {
        return compressFirstStepAnimationBitmap();
    }

    public Bitmap getSecondStepAnimationBitmap() {
        return compressSecondStepAnimationBitmap();
    }

    public Bitmap getThirdStepAnimationBitmap() {
        return compressThirdStepAnimationBitmap();
    }

    public Bitmap getForthStepAnimationBitmap() {
        return compressForthStepAnimationBitmap();
    }

    private Bitmap compressFirstStepAnimationBitmap() {
            Bitmap original = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.char_anim_1);
            firstAnimationBitmap = compress(original);
        return firstAnimationBitmap;
    }

    private Bitmap compressSecondStepAnimationBitmap() {
            Bitmap original = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.char_anim_2);
            secondAnimationBitmap = compress(original);
        return secondAnimationBitmap;
    }

    private Bitmap compressThirdStepAnimationBitmap() {
            Bitmap original = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.char_anim_3);
            thirdAnimationBitmap = compress(original);
        return thirdAnimationBitmap;
    }

    private Bitmap compressForthStepAnimationBitmap() {
            Bitmap original = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.char_anim_4);
            forthAnimationBitmap = compress(original);
        return forthAnimationBitmap;
    }

    private Bitmap compress(Bitmap original) {
        return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(original, COMPRESS_WIDTH, COMPRESS_HEIGHT, false);
    }
}
```

Player.java:

```
public class Player {

    private Bitmap bitmap;

    private int maxY;
    private int minY;
    private int x;
    private int y;

    private int speed = 40;
    int dv = 4;
    int s = 0;

    public int backgroundLayer = 0;

    public Player(Context context, int screenX, int screenY) {
        x = 75;
        y = screenY / 2;
        speed = 1;

        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.char_anim_1);

        maxY = screenY - bitmap.getHeight();
        minY = 0;
    }

    public void update(){
        x++;
    }


    public Bitmap getBitmap() {
        return bitmap;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public int getSpeed() {
        return speed;
    }

    public void move() {
        speed += dv;
        backgroundLayer -= speed/60;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Проблема решена. Оказывается, из-за того, что я в методе draw() каждый раз создаю новый экземпляр класса BitmapConstants, canvas перерисовывает bitmap, на что уходит очень много ресурсов.